# When will a static class initialize?

Tags: java, import, initialization, static-import

Consider a [Java class with static fields only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942903/java-class-with-only-static-fields-and-methods-bad-or-good-practice) and no constructor:

```java
public class OnlyStatic {
   static O1 o1 = new o1();
   static O2 o2 = new o2();

   public static int compute(int whatever) {
       return o1.foo+o2.bar+whatever;
   }
}
```

In a different class, the method `compute` is used, either by `static import`:

```java
static import OnlyStatic.compute
int a = OnlyStatic.compute(3);
```

Or directly, assuming the caller is in the same package:

```java
int a = OnlyStatic.compute(3);
```

**When are o1 and o2 initialized? At the import, or when `compute()` is called for the first time?**

Comment: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#44557

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The objects `o1` and `o2` are not available to your `static` context without making them `static` also.

[JVMS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Concepts.doc.html#32316) states that

> Any static initializers declared in a class are executed when the class is initialized

[Further](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#57949)

> A class or interface type *T* will be initialized immediately before the first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> - *T* is a class and an instance of *T* is created.
> - *T* is a class and a static method declared by *T* is invoked.
> - A static field declared by *T* is assigned.
> - A static field declared by *T* is used and the field is not a constant variable (§4.12.4).
> - *T* is a top-level class, and an assert statement (§14.10) lexically nested within *T* is 
>     executed.

So in your case, when the static method `compute()` is first *executed*.

Comment: Fixed the static declaration. What do you mean by directly? At the import, or at the first call?

Comment: "...not lazy-loaded". Strictly speaking this is not true. The class `OnlyStatic` is lazy loaded by the JVM. But the static fields are initialized immediately during the loading of the class.

Comment: @A.H. - is the class first loaded upon import or upon method call?

Comment: @AdamMatan: `import` is only known to the compiler, at runtime there is no `import`. Besides of this you might read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8550567/947357